# How to make transparent border on the triangle form?

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

[image]

As you can see, the form has double transparent border. I would be glad if you give me some link or little edit my code snippet. Its important that border transparent and has opacity somewhere 0.3-0.6

```css
form {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 30px 20px;
  border: none;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  height: 150px;
}
form .header {
  flex-basis: 100%;
  margin: -10px 0 10px;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}
form input,
form button {
  flex-grow: 1;
  height: 30px;
  margin: 0 5px;
  padding: 0 5px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
form button[type="submit"] {
  background-color: #FFD900;
}
.rhombus {
  position: relative;
  -webkit-perspective: 800px;
  perspective: 800px;
}
.rhombus:before,
.rhombus:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  height: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #1E9BAF;
  z-index: -1;
}
.rhombus:before {
  top: 0;
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(30deg);
  -webkit-transform-origin: center bottom;
  -ms-transform: rotateX(30deg);
  -ms-transform-origin: center bottom;
  transform: rotateX(30deg);
  transform-origin: center bottom;
}
.rhombus:after {
  bottom: 0;
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(-30deg);
  -webkit-transform-origin: center top;
  -ms-transform: rotateX(-30deg);
  -ms-transform-origin: center top;
  transform: rotateX(-30deg);
  transform-origin: center top;
}
```

```html
<form class="rhombus">
  <div class="header">SOME TEXT</div>
  <input name="name" placeholder="Your name"/>
  <input name="phone" placeholder="Your mobile phone"/>
  <button type="submit">SEND</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.   Although you have provided a [**link to an example or site**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it), if the link were to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem.

Comment: its another question. This about border. that about shadow

Comment: sorry, I didnt understand for the first time, Text seemed me some difficult

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this easily using CSS like in the below snippet:

- Add a `border` of the required width and color to the two pseudo-elements. Nullify the border on the bottom of `:before` pseudo-element (the one that produces the top half of the shape) and  the border on the top of `:after` pseudo-element (the one that produces the bottom half).
- Add a padding (exactly the same way as the `border`) to them and clip the background to be just within the content box alone. This would make the padding area of the element be transparent.

```css
form {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 30px 20px;
  border: none;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  height: 150px;
}
form .header {
  flex-basis: 100%;
  margin: -10px 0 10px;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}
form input,
form button {
  flex-grow: 1;
  height: 30px;
  margin: 0 5px;
  padding: 0 5px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
form button[type="submit"] {
  background-color: #FFD900;
}
.rhombus {
  position: relative;
  -webkit-perspective: 800px;
  perspective: 800px;
}
.rhombus:before,
.rhombus:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  height: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #1E9BAF;
  background-clip: content-box;
  border: 2px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  z-index: -1;
}
.rhombus:before {
  top: 0;
  padding: 2px 2px 0px 2px;
  border-width: 2px 2px 0px 2px;
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(30deg);
  -webkit-transform-origin: center bottom;
  -ms-transform: rotateX(30deg);
  -ms-transform-origin: center bottom;
  transform: rotateX(30deg);
  transform-origin: center bottom;
}
.rhombus:after {
  bottom: 0;
  padding: 0px 2px 2px 2px;
  border-width: 0px 2px 2px 2px;
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(-30deg);
  -webkit-transform-origin: center top;
  -ms-transform: rotateX(-30deg);
  -ms-transform-origin: center top;
  transform: rotateX(-30deg);
  transform-origin: center top;
}
*,
*:after,
*:before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  background: radial-gradient(circle at center, chocolate, sandybrown);
  min-height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<form class="rhombus">
  <div class="header">SOME TEXT</div>
  <input name="name" placeholder="Your name" />
  <input name="phone" placeholder="Your mobile phone" />
  <button type="submit">SEND</button>
</form>
```

---

If the inner border is actually not a transparent one (the image in question doesn't have a transparent inner border) then it becomes slightly more complex but it can still be done. We'd need linear gradient background images instead of plain solid colors, clip one layer to be within the content area while the other applies for the padding area also (using `background-clip` property).

We are using `linear-gradient` background-images because applying multiple colors, controlling the sizes are a possibility with gradients unlike solid colors.

```css
form {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 30px 20px;
  border: none;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  height: 150px;
}
form .header {
  flex-basis: 100%;
  margin: -10px 0 10px;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}
form input,
form button {
  flex-grow: 1;
  height: 30px;
  margin: 0 5px;
  padding: 0 5px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
form button[type="submit"] {
  background-color: #FFD900;
}
.rhombus {
  position: relative;
  -webkit-perspective: 800px;
  perspective: 800px;
}
.rhombus:before,
.rhombus:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  height: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(#1E9BAF, #1E9BAF), linear-gradient(white, white);
  background-clip: content-box, padding-box;
  border: 2px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  z-index: -1;
}
.rhombus:before {
  top: 0;
  padding: 2px 2px 0px 2px;
  border-width: 2px 2px 0px 2px;
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(30deg);
  -webkit-transform-origin: center bottom;
  -ms-transform: rotateX(30deg);
  -ms-transform-origin: center bottom;
  transform: rotateX(30deg);
  transform-origin: center bottom;
}
.rhombus:after {
  bottom: 0;
  padding: 0px 2px 2px 2px;
  border-width: 0px 2px 2px 2px;
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(-30deg);
  -webkit-transform-origin: center top;
  -ms-transform: rotateX(-30deg);
  -ms-transform-origin: center top;
  transform: rotateX(-30deg);
  transform-origin: center top;
}
*,
*:after,
*:before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  background: radial-gradient(circle at center, chocolate, sandybrown);
  min-height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<form class="rhombus">
  <div class="header">SOME TEXT</div>
  <input name="name" placeholder="Your name" />
  <input name="phone" placeholder="Your mobile phone" />
  <button type="submit">SEND</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Op did not seems to be found of gradients in earlier questions where chrome seems to have a bad render ( i proposed this already ;)  http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/YqBOaE ) added a blur effect for chrome and used gradients on a pseudo instead main container )

Comment: @GCyrillus: That's quite a lot of gradients mate. My second snippet uses only two. The rest is just borders and padding. The first one doesn't use gradients at all (though I doubt if that is what OP wants because the image in question doesn't tally with description). Plus, I am using Chrome only and the output of the snippet doesn't seem bad :)

Comment: yes i agree, it avoids the transform , still that rood/stairs  effects seems  not smooth enough : my chrome http://i.stack.imgur.com/b4VUM.jpg ;)

Comment: Do you mean on the slanted sides @GCyrillus? Does `backface-visibility: hidden` on the transformed elements fix it in your Chrome (are you on a Mac?).

Comment: yes, the slanted parts, i use chrome windows ... backface did not help  http://i.stack.imgur.com/3KpLU.jpg :(

Comment: i found the bag. what i should do? in IE ir appearing line on the center of the form

Comment: @MarikZuckor: Let me check and see how to fix it. You're seeing this in Edge or IE11 or both?

Comment: @MarikZuckor: I just checked in Edge and both the snippets are producing a gap between the top and bottom pieces but that happens only in the snippet. If I create a fiddle based on the same code - [Snippet 1](https://jsfiddle.net/ad81ox5j/) and [Snippet 2](https://jsfiddle.net/x84n6h4k/) there is no visible gap. I guess it is something to do with Stack Snippets than the actual code. If you still see a problem outside of the snippet also, then you could try applying the corrections made in [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kgkxxjez/).